# Log failed login attempts with Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How would I log failed login attempts with laravel 5.2 I have the auth scaffolding installed.

I have added the following to my EventsServiceProvider.php

```
 protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogAuthenticationAttempt',
    ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogin',
    ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogout',
    ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogLockout',
    ],
];
```

And in my app/Listeners/LogAuthenticationAttempt.php

I have

```
    $log = new Access_Log();
    $log->ip_address = Request::getClientIp();
    $log->is_success = 0;
    $log->save();
```

But this just logs that an login attempt has been made> I can log a successful login attempt using the LogSuccessfulLogin Listener but I cant see how to log a failed login attempt.

It has occurred to me that I could just update the is_success value on the log entry in the LogSuccessfulLogin Listener but what can I use to persist between LogAuthenticationAttempt and LogSuccessfulLogin to identify this as the same login attempt?

Comment: It looks like there exists a separate "failed" event, though not in the docs. Might be worth testing, as it seems it would do exactly what you need: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Auth/Events/Failed.html

Comment: I found this. I think not the best aproach, but you can try it: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/220/listening-for-authentication-attempts

Comment: @Pevara You are correct it works fine. Don't understand why this inst in the docs.

Comment: @user794846 good question, Laravel is a great framework, but when it comes to the docs there is room for improvement...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out there was a failed event it just wasn't in the docs I was following. See Pervara's comment.

I added this to the EventsServiceProvider.php:

```
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogFailedAuthenticationAttempt',
    ],
```

And created app/Listeners/LogFailedAuthenticationAttempt.php with the following code:

```
     /**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  Failed  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(Failed $event)
{
    $log = new Access_Log();
    $log->user_id = $event->user->id;
    $log->ip_address = Request::getClientIp();
    $log->event = 'Login Failed';
    $log->is_success = 0;
    $log->save();
}
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: Looks like the Failed event wasn't in the earlier version of 5.2.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when a non existing username is provided. Use $log->user_id= $event->credentials['user_id']; in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first check if the user exists, e.g if($event->user != null){
...then log 
}