# Why I obtain this "Class App\Listeners\LogAuthenticationAttempt does not exist" error trying to log in using a custom user provider?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-authorization

I am pretty new in **PHP** and **Laravel** framework and I am going crazy trying to implement the following task.

I am trying to follow this tutorial to implement a **custom user provider**:

https://blog.georgebuckingham.com/laravel-52-auth-custom-user-providers-drivers/

I am using **Larave 5.3** version.

I briefly expain what I need: my **Laravel** application is only a **front end** application, all the business logic, included the user authentication, is performed by a **Java back end application** that exposes **REST** web services.

Performing a call to:

```
http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login
```

and passing username and password as **basic authentication** I obtain a **JSON** response like this that represent the logged user:

```
{
  "userName": "Painkiller",
  "email": "painkiller@gmail.com",
  "enabled": true
}
```

So, in my Laravel application, I have to perform this call and then parse the previous returned JSON object to generate the authenticated object into the front end application session.

I think that the previous **custom user provide**r is the neater and most natural solution to do it, but I am obtaining an erro, I will explain the situation.

I have implemented all the **4 steps** of the previous tutorial and I think that I have correctly replaced the user provider with my **custom user provider**.

Aftere these implementation steps I performed this command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

to generate te **view** and the **routes** related to the Laravel **login** system. I expect that it is using the **custom user provider** defined by me.

So I have these routes:

```
$ php artisan route:list
+--------+----------+------------------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                    | Name     | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+------------------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                      |          | App\Http\Controllers\LoginBetriviusController@index                    | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user               |          | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | POST     | doLogin                |          | App\Http\Controllers\LoginBetriviusController@doLogin                  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                   |          | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | login                  |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                  | login    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | logout                 | logout   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST     | password/email         |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset         |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | password/reset         |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token} |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | register               | register | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | register               |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
+--------+----------+------------------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

As you can see there are the standard login routes. I think that now it have to use my **custom user provider** (the one that call my REST web service) instead the standard one.

I run the application using the statment:

```
php artisan serve
```

It starts without no error, then I access to this URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/login
```

and the login page is correctly displayed.

Then i insert the credential (e-mail and password) but when I submit the login form I obtain this error message:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 749:
Class App\Listeners\LogAuthenticationAttempt does not exist
in Container.php line 749
at ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Listeners\LogAuthenticationAttempt') in Container.php line 749
at Container->build('App\Listeners\LogAuthenticationAttempt', array()) in Container.php line 644
at Container->make('App\Listeners\LogAuthenticationAttempt', array()) in Application.php line 709
at Application->make('App\Listeners\LogAuthenticationAttempt') in Dispatcher.php line 373
at Dispatcher->createClassCallable('App\Listeners\LogAuthenticationAttempt', object(Application)) in Dispatcher.php line 354
at Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure}(object(Attempting))
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array(object(Attempting))) in Dispatcher.php line 221
at Dispatcher->fire(object(Attempting)) in SessionGuard.php line 401
at SessionGuard->fireAttemptEvent(array('email' => 'dsfsdf@sdfsdf.com', 'password' => 'fdsfsdfsdf'), true, true) in SessionGuard.php line 351
at SessionGuard->attempt(array('email' => 'dsfsdf@sdfsdf.com', 'password' => 'fdsfsdfsdf'), true) in AuthenticatesUsers.php line 77
at LoginController->attemptLogin(object(Request)) in AuthenticatesUsers.php line 42
at LoginController->login(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(LoginController), 'login'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('login', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(LoginController), 'login') in Route.php line 190
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 653
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php line 24
at RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('C:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Betrivius\WorkSpace\betriviusExtranet\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Why? What could be wrong? How can I try to ix this issue?

I am not into Laravel but searching online information about Laravel login and the problem to the missing **LogAuthenticationAttempt** class I have fount this SO post:

[Log failed login attempts with Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813677/log-failed-login-attempts-with-laravel-5-2)

Maybe it is a similar problem but I am not understanding it it could be the same situation and how to solve it.

What can I do?

Comment: If you look in your `app/Listeners/` folder, does that class actually exist in that folder?  And is the file name the same as the class name?

Comment: @user3158900 I don't have the Listeners folder into my app folder. Why? Can I generate it in some way?

Comment: Yeah it does get generated based on the contents of the `$listen` variable in `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php`.  See if it's in there and if it is, you can run the command `php artisan event:generate` and it will generate it for you.

Comment: @user3158900 YEAHHHHHHH !!! IT WORKS !!! If you post a response with this info I will happy to accept it. Tnx so much !!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try running the command `php artisan event:generate` and it will generate any  events in the `$listen` variable in your `EventServiceProvider.php` file.